# How can I access this div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How do I add active class to div while `class="btn-buy2 gecmis"` is active?

I want to add to `<div class="my-head-right-item1">`

```html
<div class="contact-box2 mb-4">
  <div class="my-meeting-toptitle align-items-center">
    <div class="my-meeting-head-left">
      <a href="#anlik" class="btn-buy2 active">Anlık</a>
      <a href="#gecmis" class="btn-buy2 gecmis">Geçmiş</a>
      <a href="#kisisel" class="btn-buy2">Kişisel Oda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="my-meeting-head-right">
      <div class="my-head-right-item1">
        Takvimi Görüntüle
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: div to which active class should be added; <div class="my-head-right-item1">

Comment: <a href="#gecmis" class="btn-buy2 gecmis (active)">Geçmiş</a>, when active is added

Comment: So now `Anlık` is active. You want to add active to `my-head-right-item1` when `Geçmiş` becomes active? What makes `Geçmiş` active? Some other code?

Comment: I think you wanted to `active` when it is clicked and remove from the other

Comment: No, I want it to be active while "my-head-right-item1" is active.

Comment: when click on `btn-buy2 gecmis` i need to select other div with javascript

Answer (score 0):

To add a class to a a div containing both btn-buy2 and gecmis classes you can do

```
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-buy2').filter(item => 
return item.classList.indexOf('gecmis') > -1);
elements.forEach(el => el.classList.add('your-class-name-here'));
```

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here I add active using an eventListener and toggle active on the other div if gecmis is active

```js
document.querySelector(".contact-box2").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (tgt.classList.contains("btn-buy2")) {
    tgt.closest("div").querySelectorAll(".btn-buy2")
      .forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove("active")); // remove active from siblings
    tgt.classList.add("active");
    tgt.closest(".my-meeting-toptitle")
      .querySelector(".my-head-right-item1")
      .classList.toggle("active", 
        tgt.classList.contains("gecmis") &&  tgt.classList.contains("active")
      );
  }
})
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="contact-box2 mb-4">
  <div class="my-meeting-toptitle align-items-center">
    <div class="my-meeting-head-left">
      <a href="#anlik" class="btn-buy2 active">Anlık</a>
      <a href="#gecmis" class="btn-buy2 gecmis">Geçmiş</a>
      <a href="#kisisel" class="btn-buy2">Kişisel Oda</a>
    </div>
    <div class="my-meeting-head-right">
      <div class="my-head-right-item1">
        Takvimi Görüntüle
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```